# Not hitting my Data Template based on datatype in ContentControl, Why not?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, entity-framework-6

None of my datatemplates are showing up based on DataType of the DataContext. The actual object being passed to the DataContext of UserControl is an Entity (EntityFrameWork 6.0).

I am specifying DataType="{x:Type pf:Promotion}" which is the name of a POCO class that the entity is based on.

(xmlns:pf="clr-namespace:PFModel;assembly=PFModel")

I am lost here, don't know where the problem lies. Thankful for any help or hints.

```
<UserControl x:Class="PFPromoEditor.UserControls.CenterEditor"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PFPromoEditor.UserControls"
         xmlns:wpfTool="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit" 
         xmlns:pf="clr-namespace:PFModel;assembly=PFModel"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">     
<Grid>
    <Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" Margin="2" Padding="5" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="8,8,8,8">
        <ContentControl>
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type pf:Promotion}">
                    <TextBox Text="Promotion DATA type" />
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type pf:Casino}">
                    <TextBox Text="Casino DATA type" />
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type pf:Progressive}">
                    <TextBlock Text="Progressive DATA type" />
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type pf:Detail}">
                    <TextBox Text="Detail DATA type" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Resources>                
        </ContentControl>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

```
<local:CenterEditor x:Name="CenterContent" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=promoMenu,Path=MySelectedItem }"/>
```

Answer to first question, the control has datacontext properly set with an entity, of either Promotion, Casino, Promotion or Detail.

I have also tried it with a bound property like:

```
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type pf:Progressive}">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="Progressive DATA type" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Detail.Title, FallbackValue= 'Select any Item in list to edit'}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
```

Still nothing, blank.

I have also just placed something like:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Detail.Title, FallbackValue= 'Select any Item in list to edit'}"/>
```

In the code above like thus:

```
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Resources>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Detail.Title, FallbackValue= 'Select any Item in list to edit'}"/>
        </ContentControl>
```

And the textbox binding is fine, the entity is there and I get the expected data.

Its not a data binding problem. I have context and I have a proper object.

I thought of a couple other things I need to try. Let me get back to you.

Comment: you have no binding on your ContentControl ? :-) ? you don't fill it with data ? so it won't work

Comment: Yes it has data context, and a line like                             <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Detail.Title, FallbackValue= 'Select any Item in list to edit'}"/> is populated when I place it in the content control with the proper data from the proper object.

Comment: ok, then the "Content" property of the ContentControl is not set. DataContext is not enough. <ContentControl Content={Binding "dot'/>

Comment: @Clemens Please explain. I know the entity type is called something else, like  Progressive_B788B3F33208E4E024375DA9041620F7051E96C2EB606600E176440BCA2FCA86 but how do your refer to that in the datatemplate type? Especially since the numbers in the entity type change.

Comment: @GCamel children of a control inherit the datacontext of the parent, the only reason you would set a datacontext at some point in the control tree is if you needed it to be something other then the parents datacontext. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @Clemens you mean like in code behind? Gawd I don't want to do that,

Comment: However, as GCamel has said, the ContentControl wouldn't automatically choose a ContentTemplate unless you set or bind its Content property.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the thing I was doing wrong (besides being stubborn about what I thought was wrong, and trying to solve my problem at 3 am, and over thinking the problem in general) was leaving out:

Content="{Binding}"

which BTW way I missed in the comments, I recall reading datacontext, that happened because I was tired and frustrated.

The thing that solved the problem was this modification to the content control

```
 <ContentControl  Content="{Binding}" >
```